# Can I use rsnapshot without a schedule?

Tags: rsnapshot

I installed [rsnapshot [image: Install rsnapshot]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/rsnapshot) and would like to use a command to perform a backup without a schedule.

I tried to find the information on [its official website](http://rsnapshot.org/) but I was only able to find information about scheduled backups. I couldn't find a simple command to perform a single backup.

How can I do that? Is there any command to perform a backup without a schedule?

Comment: What you are looking for is "rsync" if you want it command line Examples: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/rsync-command-examples/

Answer (score 0):

You can start a snapshot with a simple

```
rsnapshot <backup_interval>
```

e.g.:

```
rsnapshot daily
```

My `rsnapshot.conf` has the following entries:

```
[...]

#########################################
#           BACKUP INTERVALS            #
# Must be unique and in ascending order #
# i.e. hourly, daily, weekly, etc.      #
#########################################

# interval      hourly  15 
interval        daily   7
# interval      weekly  4                                
# interval      monthly 3

[...]
```

or with `grep`:

```
$ grep '^interval' /etc/rsnapshot.conf 
interval    daily
```